# Sidekiq to execute at specific time in every timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Using Sidekiq, what are the strategy to have it execute at a particular time in every time zone?

For example, I need Sidekiq to perform a task every day at the following time and time zones across the world:

`...
8:00 PM EST
8:00 PM CST
8:00 PM MST
8:00 PM PST
...`

Comment: What is wrong with translating that times into UTC?

Comment: We record all times in UTC in the database. Maybe my question is not clear... we have users across the world and we want to send out a "daily digest" at 8pm in each user's timezone. Does that make sense? @spickermann

Comment: [Sidekiq Enterprise](http://sidekiq.org/products/enterprise) can do this, but the free and Pro versions do not include this functionality.

Comment: And you know your users' timezone? How is that information stored (by timezone abbreviations (which might be ambiguous), offset, tz)?

Comment: Yea, we have the offset, tz, and even the lat/lon coordinates. I see that you just provided an answer below that looks like a very promising solution. Many thanks, @spickermann! Will up it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would just run the same job at the start of *each* hour. You might want to use cron to run the job each hour or have a look at this list on how to create [recurring jobs in Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Related-Projects#recurring-jobs).

The first step within the job is to figure out all time zones in which it is `8AM` right now:

```
8am_time_zones = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
                                        .select { |tz| tz.now.hour == 8 }
                                        .map { |tz| tz.tzinfo.name }
#=> ["America/Los_Angeles", "America/Tijuana", "America/Phoenix"]
```

With this list you can easily load users from your database who live in one of the time zones (assuming you stored the users' time zone in this format) and send them the email:

```
User.where(time_zone: 8am_time_zones).find_each do |user|
  # email_newsletter(recipient: user)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq has no scheduling mechanism for your use case of 'every day'.  You need a cron scheduler like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

Assuming your server is configured to UTC, you'd just create your schedule:

```
# EST 8pm
every 1.day, :at => '1:00 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_1_am_UTC"
end
# CST 8pm
every 1.day, :at => '2:00 am' do
  runner "MyOtherModel.task_to_run_at_2_am_UTC"
end
```

To do it in one line:

```
every '* 6,7,8,9,10 1 * *' do
  runner "MyOtherModel.task_to_run_at_2_am_UTC"
end
```

Take a look at how [cron syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is formulated.

Comment: Our server is set up to UTC -- but we want to run the SAME recurring task (eg: `MyModel.task_1`) in EVERY timezone at a specific time (eg: 8:00 PM). Is this possible with the `whenever` gem?

Comment: Yes, you'd just use cron syntax.

Comment: Updated my answer @ChadTaylor

Answer (score 0):

Create this job and execute every 1 hour and 1 minute

```rb
class ScheduleBasedOnTimeZoneJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    # only execute in the beggening if the day
    return unless now.to_i - now.beginning_of_day.to_i < 300

    time_zones = ["America/Los_Angeles", "America/Tijuana", "America/Phoenix"]
    time_zones.each do |time_zone|
      now = Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone)

      # Schedule job at 08:00 AM based on the provided timezone
      schedule_at = now.change(hour: 8, min: 0)
      MyTzBasedJob.set(wait_until: schedule_at).perform_later(time_zone: time_zone)
    end
  end
end
```