# Ruby - Is there a way to get the timestamp for a specific future time but have that be dependent on timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

I have an email system. I want to send emails to people at 8AM local time. If I have their timezone in this format: "America/New_York" how can I get a Time object with the next instance of 8AM for that timezone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373389/sidekiq-to-execute-at-specific-time-in-every-timezones

Comment: @spickermann Thanks but that didn't really help with my situation

Comment: Do you want to send these emails every day at 8AM and therefore need to know at what time in your server's timezone is 8AM in each user's timezone? Or do you just need to send an email once an therefore only need to know the next time at in your timezone at which it is 8AM in the timezone of a particular user?

Comment: @spickermann The latter. We are basically scheduling the emails to be sent at a certain time but are queuing them up now but with a different delivery time. We want to schedule it so the emails are delivered at 8 am local time for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a `User` model and each user has its timezone stored in an attribute `timezone` and `timezone #=> 'America/New_York'`.

Then you can add a method like the following to your `User` model:

```
def next_time_it_is_8am_in_this_users_timezone_in_utc
  time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[timezone].now.change(hour: 8)
  time = time + 1.day if time.past?
  
  time.utc
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much clearer than the code I ended up with.