# Schedule Cron job for different timezones rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, timezone, sidekiq

I want to schedule a cron job that would send emails to all users as soon as deadline for their events ended. Note: Every user have different timezone.

The approach i was thinking about:
I have a cron job that will run every day at 11 PM of UTC. This approach does work but every user will receive email according to UTC i.e at 1am, 3am or 4pm. Not according to their timezone.

```
* 23 * * * 'UTC'
```

Comment: This sounds very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373389/sidekiq-to-execute-at-specific-time-in-every-timezones

Comment: @spickermann
 I checked this also this approach is very expensive in my case what if I have only 5 or 6 users whose deadline is reached but job will run for all timezones which are more than 20.

Answer (score 2):

You can just run the same job at an interval of every 30 minutes so that it covers all the timezones. This should work:

```
# run this every 30 minutes
time_zones_with_23 = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select { |tz| tz.now.hour == 23 }.map { |tz| tz.tzinfo.name }
user_list = User.where(time_zone: time_zones_with_23)
```

Answer (score 1):

First run this command on rails console

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

you will see the result like this

```
> [#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e4945f8 @name="International
> Date Line West", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Etc/GMT+12>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e48ea90
> @name="American Samoa", @utc_offset=nil,
> @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Pago_Pago>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e48fbc0 @name="Midway Island", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Midway>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e48d438 @name="Hawaii", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Honolulu>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e487998 @name="Alaska", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Juneau>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e43cc68 @name="Pacific Time (US & Canada)", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Los_Angeles>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e3de4d8
> @name="Tijuana", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Tijuana>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e364570
> @name="Arizona", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Phoenix>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd6098160a0
> @name="Mazatlan", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Mazatlan>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e38d4e8
> @name="Mountain Time (US & Canada)", @utc_offset=nil,
> @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Denver>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e307960 @name="Central America", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Guatemala>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd6080ea728 @name="Central Time (US & Canada)", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Chicago>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60980e5d0
> @name="Chihuahua", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Chihuahua>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e31c180
> @name="Guadalajara", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Mexico_City>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e30ef58
> @name="Mexico City", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Mexico_City>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e30eee0
> @name="Monterrey", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Monterrey>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e3264c8
> @name="Saskatchewan", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Regina>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2944b0
> @name="Bogota", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Bogota>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e3067e0
> @name="Eastern Time (US & Canada)", @utc_offset=nil,
> @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/New_York>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2cd148 @name="Indiana (East)", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Indiana/Indianapolis>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e28f2a8 @name="Lima", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Lima>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e28d070 @name="Quito", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Lima>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e28cff8 @name="Atlantic Time (Canada)", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Halifax>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e225e98
> @name="Caracas", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Caracas>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e10ea28
> @name="Georgetown", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Guyana>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2248b8
> @name="La Paz", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/La_Paz>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e107778
> @name="Puerto Rico", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Puerto_Rico>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e21e1e8
> @name="Santiago", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Santiago>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60722a328
> @name="Newfoundland", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/St_Johns>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e157070
> @name="Brasilia", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Sao_Paulo>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e145a28
> @name="Buenos Aires", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e1056d0 @name="Greenland", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Godthab>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e136aa0 @name="Montevideo", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Montevideo>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e0751c0 @name="Mid-Atlantic", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Atlantic/South_Georgia>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e0741f8
> @name="Azores", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Atlantic/Azores>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7ebdd8
> @name="Cape Verde Is.", @utc_offset=nil,
> @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Atlantic/Cape_Verde>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d681d30 @name="Casablanca", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Africa/Casablanca>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7ea398 @name="Dublin", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Dublin>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d778810 @name="Edinburgh", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/London>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d6f1310 @name="Lisbon", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Lisbon>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d681dd0 @name="London", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/London>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d661788 @name="Monrovia", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Africa/Monrovia>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d36ab60 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Etc/UTC>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd608109ee8 @name="Amsterdam", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Amsterdam>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d65b860 @name="Belgrade", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Belgrade>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e6efb90 @name="Berlin", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Berlin>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e6b42e8 @name="Bern", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Zurich>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d5ba7f8 @name="Bratislava", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Bratislava>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60add64f8 @name="Brussels", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Brussels>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d4ef3c8 @name="Budapest", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Budapest>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd6071784e8 @name="Copenhagen", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Copenhagen>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d4118e8 @name="Ljubljana", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Ljubljana>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60ab629b0 @name="Madrid", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Madrid>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60a8ffa60 @name="Paris", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Paris>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d2bba20 @name="Prague", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Prague>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e67c3e8 @name="Rome", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Rome>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d17a648 @name="Sarajevo", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Sarajevo>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d0e8a90 @name="Skopje", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Skopje>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e6377c0 @name="Stockholm", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Stockholm>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e5fdae8 @name="Vienna", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Vienna>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d02f518 @name="Warsaw", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/Warsaw>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e5c7f10 @name="West Central Africa", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Africa/Algiers>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60af4cfa8
> @name="Zagreb", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Zagreb>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e67c460
> @name="Zurich", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Zurich>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e3b6d70
> @name="Athens", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Athens>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e5c4860
> @name="Bucharest", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Bucharest>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e585a20
> @name="Cairo", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Africa/Cairo>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e304148
> @name="Harare", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Africa/Harare>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd603be3eb8
> @name="Helsinki", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Helsinki>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd609814ac0
> @name="Jerusalem", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Jerusalem>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2fde60
> @name="Kaliningrad", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Kaliningrad>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e546b40
> @name="Kyiv", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Kiev>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2ff508
> @name="Pretoria", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Africa/Johannesburg>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e50c260
> @name="Riga", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Riga>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e4cdd58
> @name="Sofia", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Sofia>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e486980
> @name="Tallinn", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Tallinn>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e425838
> @name="Vilnius", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Vilnius>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2cd4e0
> @name="Baghdad", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Baghdad>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e375668
> @name="Istanbul", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Istanbul>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd603bf85e8
> @name="Kuwait", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Kuwait>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60980eb98
> @name="Minsk", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Minsk>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2ef4a0
> @name="Moscow", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Moscow>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2cee80
> @name="Nairobi", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Africa/Nairobi>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2cf9e8
> @name="Riyadh", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Riyadh>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2dc2d8 @name="St.
> Petersburg", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Moscow>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2dc260
> @name="Volgograd", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Volgograd>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2c59e8
> @name="Tehran", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Tehran>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2b6d30 @name="Abu
> Dhabi", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Muscat>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2b5f70
> @name="Baku", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Baku>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2b6010
> @name="Muscat", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Muscat>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd603c020c0
> @name="Samara", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Europe/Samara>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2a7290
> @name="Tbilisi", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Tbilisi>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e29d1f0
> @name="Yerevan", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Yerevan>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e28ed80
> @name="Kabul", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Kabul>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e28dd90
> @name="Ekaterinburg", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Yekaterinburg>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e284790
> @name="Islamabad", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Karachi>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e27e868
> @name="Karachi", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Karachi>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e27e7c8
> @name="Tashkent", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Tashkent>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e277e50
> @name="Chennai", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Kolkata>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e276320
> @name="Kolkata", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Kolkata>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e276168
> @name="Mumbai", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Kolkata>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e275ee8
> @name="New Delhi", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Kolkata>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e26eeb8
> @name="Sri Jayawardenepura", @utc_offset=nil,
> @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Colombo>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e275e70 @name="Kathmandu", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Kathmandu>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e25ff58 @name="Almaty", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Almaty>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e274ea8 @name="Astana", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Dhaka>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e26ef58 @name="Dhaka", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Dhaka>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e1fccc8 @name="Urumqi", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Urumqi>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e23d0c0 @name="Rangoon", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Rangoon>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e2355a0 @name="Bangkok", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Bangkok>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e22fb50 @name="Hanoi", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Bangkok>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e22fab0 @name="Jakarta", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Jakarta>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e22c3b0 @name="Krasnoyarsk", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Krasnoyarsk>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e254748 @name="Novosibirsk", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Novosibirsk>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e21d2e8 @name="Beijing", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Shanghai>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e215250 @name="Chongqing", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Chongqing>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e20d118 @name="Hong Kong", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Hong_Kong>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e1cfc50 @name="Irkutsk", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Irkutsk>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e1f72c8 @name="Kuala Lumpur", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Kuala_Lumpur>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e1d7310 @name="Perth", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Australia/Perth>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e1eea60 @name="Singapore", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Singapore>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e1e6ba8 @name="Taipei", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Taipei>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e1c4030 @name="Ulaanbaatar", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Ulaanbaatar>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd607229d10 @name="Osaka", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Tokyo>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd607223f50 @name="Sapporo", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Tokyo>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e1bc038 @name="Seoul", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Seoul>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd607223e10 @name="Tokyo", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Tokyo>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd607223c58 @name="Yakutsk", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Yakutsk>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd6080e4350 @name="Adelaide", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Australia/Adelaide>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd6080e6970 @name="Darwin", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Australia/Darwin>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e05fa50 @name="Brisbane", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Australia/Brisbane>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e14c968 @name="Canberra", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Australia/Melbourne>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7da9e8
> @name="Guam", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Pacific/Guam>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e057c38
> @name="Hobart", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Australia/Hobart>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e0d7460
> @name="Melbourne", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Australia/Melbourne>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7d2630
> @name="Port Moresby", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Pacific/Port_Moresby>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e0d7320
> @name="Sydney", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Australia/Sydney>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7e9bc8
> @name="Vladivostok", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Vladivostok>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7d0d80
> @name="Magadan", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Asia/Magadan>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7a89e8
> @name="New Caledonia", @utc_offset=nil,
> @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Noumea>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7a9a28 @name="Solomon Is.", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone:
> Pacific/Guadalcanal>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7c22a8
> @name="Srednekolymsk", @utc_offset=nil,
> @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Srednekolymsk>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d788878 @name="Auckland", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Auckland>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7a2db8 @name="Fiji", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Fiji>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d79aa78 @name="Kamchatka", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Asia/Kamchatka>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d78a808 @name="Marshall Is.", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Majuro>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d711868 @name="Wellington", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Auckland>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d709cd0 @name="Chatham Is.", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Chatham>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d7117a0 @name="Nuku'alofa", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Tongatapu>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d6a9d08 @name="Samoa", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Apia>>,
> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60d70b008 @name="Tokelau Is.", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Pacific/Fakaofo>>]
```

Let suppose we want to set time for Brisbane

```
#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007fd60e05fa50 @name="Brisbane", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Australia/Brisbane>>
```

we use it like this

```
:schedule:
  fetch_inventories:
    cron: '0 13 * * * Australia/Brisbane'   # everyday at 1:PM
    class: FetchInventories
```

you can set time using https://crontab.guru/